# How to Divide a Vue 3 Project into Smaller Apps with Shared Functionality, Routes, and Stores

Tags: typescript, vue.js

So our team is working on a big Vue 3 project, and we had an idea of dividing that big app into smaller apps each one with its own components, routes, stores and so so.

The idea is like this, there will be a `base` Vue app which will have all the common functionality and each app will extend it, and then all the apps will be included in the main app.

each one of these apps should run perfectly fine one its own, and the main app should run fine with 1 or more apps.

The main app should only show features and routes from the apps that were included in it, for example if we had `base` app, and 2 apps one for `users` and the other one is for `books`, the main app can extend one or more apps.

This image explains what I am trying to do

[image]

I tried using Nuxt 3 `extends` feature but it was really complecated and I don't think it fits my usecase, I need to namespace each app routes and stores.

Comment: Probably the question for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com and not SO, but it's lacking, it's unclear what the case really looks like, you mention Nuxt but it's unknown if you use it. Can be handled with a monorepo or sub-apps with multiple entry points in Vite/Vue CLI. There should be extendable things in base/ dir like route factory function that contains common routes